# Query Statements by Activity For Multiple Agents

Tags: learning-locker, xapi

Is there a way to query the LRS for an Activity based on a collection of Agents?

Looking at the Learning Locker documentation it seems that you cannot query against a collection of Agents unless you had previously associated them with a Group. My scenario is querying against 100,000 Agents at once.

http://docs.learninglocker.net/http-xapi-statements/

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there is no way to "filter" the statement stream based on multiple agents at once. The xAPI specification was never intended to provide full query capability with the assumption that companion specs would be produced to codify those needs, as they are complex and difficult and beyond what xAPI's scope was at the time. Requests to the `GET /statements` resource are best thought of as a stream with limiting filters rather than as a "query" interface.

Generally the expectation is that the LRS will maintain the full source of truth for the data and that the statements are portable to other systems that are better equipped for querying, such as indexing systems, data warehouses, reporting tools, etc.